# Writing portable Scheme code

Tags: scheme, lisp, portability

I am about to start a Scheme project. All the programming is pretty straightforward, and I am trying to make my program portable, which means easily executed or installed in other machines where Scheme is already installed.
My program is supposed to handle input in file format and output results to the screen and also save data as files.

### My Questions are:

1. What kind of permissions should be given to my program?
2. Is there a compiler that can compile my Scheme program into an executable file for Unix or Windows Systems?

Thanks in advance
Note: I am working in Ubuntu

Comment: possible duplicate of [Writing portable scheme code. Is anything "standard" beyond R5RS itself?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11062320/writing-portable-scheme-code-is-anything-standard-beyond-r5rs-itself)

Comment: @AlexisKing  I disagree. That question is strictly about portability between Scheme implementations and understandability by Schemer programmers, while this questioner seems more interested in portability between *machines* and the ability of end users to run the code. The latter form of portability is a completely different question than portability between (for example) Guile and MIT Scheme.

Comment: @TAnas What kind of portability do you have in mind? Portability between Scheme implementations or between platforms (Windows, OS X, Linux etc). If the later Racket is a good choice.

Comment: I am trying to achieve portability where my code can be executed under different platforms (Windows, Linux...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing standard-compliant Scheme imposes strict limits on what you can do. The R5RS standard is very small, and doesn't include such basic things as error handling, or even detecting which compiler/interpreter your code is running on. The R6RS standard is more extensive, but not widely implemented. Therefore, writing a Scheme program that will run on whatever Scheme interpreter or compiler that happens to be installed on the user's machine is difficult.

That doesn't matter too much, however, because Scheme is not widely installed. Chances are that your end user will not have any Scheme interpreter installed, except maybe in the guise of libguile, but that's a C library.

You can have *platform* portability by targeting a specific implementation of Scheme, which chances are you'll have to do anyway because you'll need to rely on some implementation's extensions to the Scheme standard to get any work done.

[Chicken Scheme](http://call-cc.org/) has a compiler that produces small executables, and it purports to run on both Windows and Unix. I've only used it on Linux, however.

The commercial [Chez Scheme](http://www.scheme.com/) also has a compiler that produces executables on both Windows and Linux, but I've never used any version of Chez Scheme on any platform.

[Racket](http://racket-lang.org/) can produce executables on Windows, Linux, and MacOS. However, the language deviates from Scheme considerably. For example, lists are immutable in Racket. Racket has a big library that includes things like networking and GUIs, all fully portable between operating systems. The compiler produces big executables.

[SISC](http://sisc-scheme.org/) runs on the JVM, making it portable to anything that Java runs on. However, it's an interpreter, not a compiler.

All of the above have foreign function interfeces to C (or to Java in the case of SISC).

Comment: You can write both standard R5RS and R6RS and use SRFIs and still compile with Racket. You can use racket libraries that does not involve pairs from `#!racket` but then you have to implement these to move your code to a different implementation. Gambit also compile to c, like chicken.

Comment: @Sylwester There's no need to cripple your program by conforming to R5RS if you're using Racket. Racket itself is highly portable.

Comment: It really is better to conform to a standard. When Paul Graham implemented Arc it broke because Racket suddenly decided to make pairs immutable. You have no guarantee Racket won't do the same again and stop supporting something or change semantics. Sticking with R6RS keeps the doors open for moving to Ikarus or other compatible R6RS implementations. What you don't have via R6RS and SRFIs you can wrap from `#!racket` so it's pretty clear what you need to reimplement.